# horizontal line color and thickness

Tags: pine-script

I'd like the code to make a horizontal like on the chart that extends to the left and right and can change the color and width to what I like. The stock horizontal line doesn't have enough thickness for me.

Comment: Can you please share your code so we can see the way you are using the `hline()` function? It should have enough thickness to be honest.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like the standard settings for horizontal lines doesn't meet your needs.  You can easily add thicker lines with pinescript's

```
  hline(price, title, color, linestyle, linewidth, editable)
```

just set the color and the linewidth properties.

```
//@version=5
indicator("HLines",overlay=true)

// add thick 20 pixel blue line @ 4700 on ES chart
hline(4700,"", color=color.blue, 
      linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=20)

// script needs plot to compile - so plot nothing...
plot(0, display=display.none)
```

Adding the ability to only display line on certain securities is left as an exercise for the reader.